# Convert codeblocks from asciidoc to markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm trying to convert some documents from asciidoc format to Markdown. Since `pandoc` can't do that on its own, I use `asciidoctor` too to convert to an intermediate docbook file:

```
asciidoctor -v -a leveloffset=+1 -d book -b docbook -s test.adoc -o test.xml
pandoc --highlight-style=pygments -f docbook --atx-headers -t markdown_strict test.xml -o test.Md
```

It seems that code blocks are not converted properly. They are ok in docbook, but when converted in Md I just have a generic blockquoted block, without syntax highlighting. Here's an example.

Original asciidoc block:

```
[source,c++]
....
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Declaring one integer variable named a
    int a;

    // Declaring two at once: b and c
    int b, c;

    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;

    // print out the values of our variables
    printf("a is %d, b is %d, and c is %d.\n", a, b, c);

    return a + b + c;
}
....
```

Docbook block:

```
<programlisting language="c++" linenumbering="unnumbered">#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;

int main(void)
{
    // Declaring one integer variable named a
    int a;

    // Declaring two at once: b and c
    int b, c;

    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;

    // print out the values of our variables
    printf("a is %d, b is %d, and c is %d.\n", a, b, c);

    return a + b + c;
}</programlisting>
```

Markdown I've got (just indented)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Declaring one integer variable named a
    int a;

    // Declaring two at once: b and c
    int b, c;

    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;

    // print out the values of our variables
    printf("a is %d, b is %d, and c is %d.\n", a, b, c);

    return a + b + c;
}
```

Expected Markdown:

````
```c++
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Declaring one integer variable named a
    int a;

    // Declaring two at once: b and c
    int b, c;

    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;

    // print out the values of our variables
    printf("a is %d, b is %d, and c is %d.\n", a, b, c);

    return a + b + c;
}
```
````

I'm using pandoc 2.9.2.1

Are some options or tweaks I can use to tune up the output?

Comment: you'll have to post example docbook input and expected/actual markdown output. also make sure you use the newest pandoc version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `markdown_strict`. Using a different markdown variant and pandoc `backtick_code_blocks` extension will solve, ie:

```
pandoc --highlight-style=pygments -f docbook -t markdown-backtick_code_blocks test.xml -o test.Md
```